# java.sql.SQLException: No operations allowed after statement closed when trying to update a value

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I am getting this exception when trying to update an sql value.
`java.sql.SQLException: No operations allowed after statement closed.`
I know that this is mostlikely because I am trying to reuse the statement. Would I have to make a new statement to prevent this error?

Here is my code:

```
static Statement stat;
static ResultSet rs;
static ResultSetMetaData rsmd;
```

first instance of using statement:

```
public static void connectDB(String url, String username, String password) {
        try ( Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password)) {

            stat = conn.createStatement();
            rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM rewards");
            rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
            
            while(rs.next()) {
                accountsAndOrders.getRewards().add(new Reward(rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3), rs.getString(4), rs.getDouble(5)));
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Connection failed..");
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
```

second instance is used when a button is clicked:

```
try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password) ){
                stat.executeUpdate("UPDATE `foods`,`rewards` SET `code` = 'test' WHERE (`id-rewards` = '1')");
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
```

Thank you for the help, I appreciate it!

Comment: I appologize if this post is repetitive, however the post I found with the MOST similarity to mine was closed down and had no answers. I apprecate any help at all, thank you!

Comment: Never share Statement, create it as local variable in each method. In your second example the stmt applies to the other `conn` instance which is closed.